# Rails Devise: detecting login method of the FB / Linkedin / local user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise with Omniauth gems for Facebook and Linkedin logins. My app allows users to login with FB / Linkedin and local credentials. Is there any good way of detecting how the current user logged in to the system?

The best thing I figured out so far is to save a flag into the user model from the appropriate OmniauthCallbacksController method, which is called on a user login. This doesn't cover the local login though.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a column :providers as a string to your user model, it should store the current users method of loggin in.
Add user.provider = auth['provider'] to your definition in your user model and you should be good.

This reference may help clarify: http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/02/09/facebook-connect-with-rails-omniauth-devise/

Good luck :)